# Error compiling Magento2

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

I have an error during the compilation due to a not completed developed module. As I'm still working on the module I would disable it and continue the compilation. I used to do that on magento1.

I tried:

1. disable it with `magento module:disable`
2. run `magento setup:upgrade`
3. run the compilation again
4. Check app/etc/config.php the module name is not included

but magento keeps reporting error.

Is the only way to get rid of the module folder?

Comment: which error are you facing ?

Comment: Post the error message here please

Comment: I think the error is not important as I'm still working on the module, I just want to disable it and run the compilation [Exception]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Warning: Declaration of Module::save should be compatible with AbstractModel::save() in /Volumes/M2/mage22/app/code  
  Module/model.php on line 16

Comment: can you show your file code?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I can, but I think it's not important as I'm still working on the module, I only would like to disable it and continue with compilation

Comment: without check your file cant find whats the real issue

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya the point is I have a module under development but I need to run the compilation. On magento1 I could disable the module and continue the work whatever the error was. That seems not be possible in magento2. Is it?

Comment: You can disable module from app/etc/config.php set value to 0

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I run the module disable and checked in app/etc/config.php there is not any more

Comment: just delet entry from setup_module table and remove var folder from root.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya still error, it seems the compilation doesn't consider if a module is enabled or not

Comment: only thing working is to move the module folder out of app/code/namespace

Comment: just remove registration.php file from module or rename it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64240/discussion-between-antonio-pedicini-and-rakesh-jesadiya).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to get rid of any of the module from compilation,

You just need to remove **registration.php** file from your module. Removing registration.php file from module, module will not consideration inside **di:compile**

if you just disable module using command at that time compilation consider all of those files of module.

**Best way is remove registration.php file or rename it to get rid off from compilation.**

Thanks.