# How to Remove Runtime Exception during Setup:di:compile command in magento 2.1.12?

Tags: magento-2.1, exception, setup-di-compile, runtime

> [RuntimeException]
>   Source class "\Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleLabelInterface" for
>   "Magent     o\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleLabelInterfaceFactory"
>   generation does not exist     .

Comment: Try to delete `{{magento root path}}/var/generation/Magento` then re-run  `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename **registration.php** of module which is throwing compilation error.

Reference : [Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190067/error-compiling-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom code? Because `RuleLabelInterface` is part of the `Magento_SalesRule`-module, not the `Magento_CatalogRule`.

Try running `setup:di:compile` with the `-vvv`-argument to see the trace which is throwing the error. I'm guessing some module is instantiating the wrong class (and I doubt if it's Magento).

Comment: Yes,i make one custom module for catalogrule.

Comment: You're probably using `Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleLabelInterfaceFactory` in your module instead of `Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleLabelInterfaceFactory`. (and for that reason probably also `Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleLabelInterface` instead of ``Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleLabelInterface`.